# How to fix the style of the tabs (also the font and to make them more thinner)

Tags: react-native

“I'm setting up a new component of top tabs navigator and I want to make them with style thinner and also change the font and etc.
so I want to know how I do it.

This is for a new component for top tab navigator

```
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

let Results = props => {
  console.log(props)
  switch (props.navigation.state.key) {
    case 'Products': {
      return props.screenProps.suggestions.products.map(pr => <Text>{pr.product_title}</Text>)
      break
    }
    case 'Brands': {
      return props.screenProps.suggestions.warehouses.map(pr => <Text>{pr.warehouse_name}</Text>)
      break
    }

    case 'Categories': {
      return props.screenProps.suggestions.categories.map(pr => <Text>{pr.categories}</Text>)
      break
    }

    case 'Upcs': {
      return props.screenProps.suggestions.upcs.map(pr => <Text>{pr.product_title}</Text>)
      break
    }

    case 'Tags': {
      return props.screenProps.suggestions.tags.map(pr => <Text>{pr.product_title}</Text>)
      break
    }
  }
  return <Text>Home</Text>
}

const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Products: Results,
  Brands: Results,
  Categories: Results,
  UPC: Results,
  Tags: Results,
})

let f = Component => {
  let r = props => {
    // alert(props)
    return <Component {...props} />
  }
  return r
}

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator)
```

I expect to make a thinner style and also change the font and so on.
so I want to know how I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tabBarOptions` in `TabNavigatorConfig` of [`createMaterialTopTabNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html)

```js
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Products: Results,
  Brands: Results,
  Categories: Results,
  UPC: Results,
  Tags: Results,
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    style: {/* tab bar style */},
    labelStyle: {/* tab label style */},
    // etc
  }
})
```